# How to compare the values in two dictionaries (as a list with multiple list entries) in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I am trying to compare two dictionaries one key:value pair each. The keys in the two dictionaries are not the same. The values consist of a list of multiple numbers. 
I want to find all value numbers that appear in both dictionaries but my code returns the following error: unhashable type: "list". 
Any ideas how I can solve this error? Thanks in advance for any support!

```
d_MS = {"74286565":[1672118498, 72935438163394562, 3597763396, 1099812539549011970]}
d_eco = {"36146779": [170742628, 3597763396, 247113642, 1130696607027138560, 162853322]}

d1_values = set(d_MS.values())
d2_values = set(d_eco.values())
in_both = d1_values & d2_values
not_in_both = d1_values ^ d2_values
```

What I would like to get is a list of all numbers that appear in both dictionaries, in this example this would be

```
[3597763396]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) of two given sets A and B is a set which consists of all the elements which are common to both A and B.

**Ex.**

```
d_MS = {"74286565":[1672118498, 72935438163394562, 3597763396, 1099812539549011970]}
d_eco = {"36146779": [170742628, 3597763396, 247113642, 1130696607027138560, 162853322]}

x = list(set(d_MS['74286565']).intersection(d_eco['36146779']))
#or
#x = list(set(*d_MS.values()).intersection(*d_eco.values()))

print(x)
```

**O/P:**

```
[3597763396]
```

Comment: Thanks, bharatk! This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Use * with it, it will unpack the values to the list, as `.values()` returns a `dict_values` object.

```
d_MS = {"74286565":[1672118498, 72935438163394562, 3597763396, 1099812539549011970]}
d_eco = {"36146779": [170742628, 3597763396, 247113642, 1130696607027138560, 162853322]}

d1_values = set(*d_MS.values())
d2_values = set(*d_eco.values())
in_both = d1_values & d2_values
not_in_both = d1_values ^ d2_values
print(in_both)
print(not_in_both)
```

Output:

```
{3597763396}
{1130696607027138560, 247113642, 1099812539549011970, 1672118498, 170742628, 72935438163394562, 162853322}
```

If your use case requires list, you can do this:

```
list(in_both)
```

Output

```
[3597763396]
```

**Note**: It will only work if there is one key:value pair each, as specified by you in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

the `.values()` methods returns a `dict_values` object, convert it to a list which will return a list of the with the values. In this case, there is only one value which will be a list itself.

```
d_MS = {"74286565":[1672118498, 72935438163394562, 3597763396, 1099812539549011970]}
d_eco = {"36146779": [170742628, 3597763396, 247113642, 1130696607027138560, 162853322]}

# here the `dict_value` object is converted into a list, and the list of values 
# has the one item, which was a list in the first place hence the indexing
d1_values = set(list(d_MS.values())[0])
d2_values = set(list(d_eco.values())[0])
in_both = d1_values & d2_values
not_in_both = d1_values ^ d2_values


print(in_both, not_in_both)
```

this will print

```
{3597763396} {1130696607027138560, 247113642, 1099812539549011970, 1672118498, 170742628, 72935438163394562, 162853322}
```

Another way to do it would be to unpack the values from the `dict_values` object and hence `set(*d_MS.values())`